# Getting indexOutOfBoundsException and I don't know why

Tags: arraylist, mouselistener

I have been having this problem for a few hours. I don't know what it is, but I am having a hard time thinking clearly at the moment. This method displays a set of images. The first part of the method is just setting the gridbag constraints, whereas the next part in the if statement is creating jlabels and adding them to an arraylist of jlabels. The exception is being thrown when I try and add mouselisteners to the jlabels after they have been added to the arraylist (this is on line 112, and i have commented this on the code).

```
public void displayComplexStimulus(BufferedImage[] complexStimulus){



    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
        if (i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2){
            c.gridx = i;
            c.gridy = 0;
        }
        else if(i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 5){
            c.gridx = i - 3;
            c.gridy = 1;
        }
        else {
            c.gridx = i - 6;
            c.gridy = 2;
        }

        if(counter == 1){



                if (phase1Trial.getPositionOfCorrectImage()!= i){
                    phase1IncorrectLabels.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(complexStimulus[i])));
                    phase1IncorrectLabels.get(i).addMouseListener(this);  //line 112
                    add(phase1IncorrectLabels.get(i),c);
                }

                else if(phase1Trial.getPositionOfCorrectImage() == i){
                    correctLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(complexStimulus[i]));
                    add(correctLabel, c);
                    correctLabel.addMouseListener(this);

                }
        }

    }





}
```

Comment: Unrelated but you might consider replacing your big `if`s by `if(i <= 2)... else if(i <= 5)... else...`

Comment: numberOfElements has the value 6. phase1IncorrectLabels are the labels in the task that are incorrect if the person clicks on them. They get shown 6 labels simultaneously, and they must click on the correct one. So, one out of the 6 are correct.

Comment: I think I partially fixed my problem. Sometimes, the else if condition was satisfied, and so an element wouldn't be added the incorrectLabels array, and so when the i in the for loop incremented, there were not enough elements in the array. I am still having problems though, because it seems like the mouselistener method is not responding to the incorrectlabels, which makes me think the addMouseListener method is not adding the listeners to the labels properly

Answer (score 0):

If `i==phase1Trial.getPositionOfCorrectImage()` you're not adding an element to `phase1IncorrectLabels`. So in the next iteration after adding one element to the array it's at position `i-1` and not `i`. You should replace your `get(i)` by `get(phase1IncorrectLabels.size() - 1)`.

Comment: Right, yeah. Do you know why I might be having the problem with the mouseListener method?

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: The jlabels do not seem to be responding when I add mouselisteners to them (you can see in the above code where I have added the mouselisteners). In my mousepressed method, the code does not reach this line of code:      else if((e.getSource() == phase1IncorrectLabels.get(0)) || (e.getSource() == phase1IncorrectLabels.get(1)) || (e.getSource() == phase1IncorrectLabels.get(2)) || (e.getSource() == phase1IncorrectLabels.get(3)) || (e.getSource() == phase1IncorrectLabels.get(4))){

Comment: This makes me think that the mouselisteners are not being added properly to the jlabels

Comment: No, wait. I figured it out. I had initialised my ArrayList in a strange place rather than every time a new instance was created, so every trial, I was adding more and more elements to an existing ArrayList rather than having it reset every time. All though I have now noticed that whenever I click an incorrect JLabel is calling parts of the mousePressed method four rather than one times, so I need to figure that out now.